# IntelliJ IDEA: Run specific maven goals with specific modules

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Can I run two install goals on two different modules with one button ?
I think this could be done with single maven command line, but I don't know how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible right now, [submitted a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-71310), please vote.

Comment: Thanks for creating feature request